# Can't edit HTML of a field in admin area

Tags: magento2, admin, adminhtml, adminform, renderer

I want to edit HTML of "Url key" field in product editing form in Magento 2 admin area appending some additional HTML to it. Magento 2.2.9.

I tried editing method `UrlKeyRenderer::getElementHtml()` but this method doesn't seem to be called when I open the product editing page, because if I change what the method returns or even if I just throw a `LocalizedException` at the beginning of the method, nothing is changed on the product editing page.

Cleaning page cache with `bin/magento cache:flush` doesn't help.

How do I change the field's HTML?

This is the field I want to edit:

[image]

Comment: what kind of HTML you want to attach with it?

Comment: @HassanAliShahzad Why does it matter? A link.

Comment: Do you want to edit this: http://prntscr.com/pt6mxn ??

Comment: @ElsdenIep Yup, added this image to the post

Comment: please show us your code

Comment: Why do you want to edit that in such a complicated way?
I am not sure what you want to accomplish. Here are some tips.  
- make sure you are in the correct Store View
- edit your url rewrites in: Admin -> MARKETING -> SEO & Search -> URL Rewrites. Edit the URL you want to change. Elaborate answer below.
- have a look here: https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/marketing/url-rewrite.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override html template that assigned for `URL Key` field by below method

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/di.xml

Create modifier pool to modify product admin form

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Pool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="modifiers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="customhtml" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\CustomHtml</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">100</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/CustomHtml.php

Add your custom component for url key

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductAttributeInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\AbstractModifier;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\ArrayManager;

/**
 * Data provider for customhtml
 */
class CustomHtml extends AbstractModifier
{

    const XML_PATH_SEO_SAVE_HISTORY = 'catalog/seo/save_rewrites_history';

    /**
     * @var ArrayManager
     */
    protected $arrayManager;

    /**
     * @param ArrayManager $arrayManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        ArrayManager $arrayManager
    ) {
        $this->arrayManager = $arrayManager;
    }

    public function modifyMeta(array $meta)
    {

        $meta = $this->addCustomHtml($meta);
        return $meta;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function modifyData(array $data)
    {
        return $data;
    }

    private function addCustomHtml(array $meta)
    {
        $urlPath = $this->arrayManager->findPath(
            ProductAttributeInterface::CODE_SEO_FIELD_URL_KEY,
            $meta,
            null,
            'children'
        );
        if ($urlPath) {
            $containerPath = $this->arrayManager->slicePath($urlPath, 0, -2);
            $meta = $this->arrayManager->merge($containerPath, $meta, [
                'arguments' => [
                    'data' => [
                        'config' => [
                            'component' => 'Vendor_Module/js/form/components/group',
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ]);
        }

        return $meta;
    }
}
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/web/js/form/components/group.js

Add your custom template in your component

```
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/**
 * @api
 */
define([
    'underscore',
    'uiCollection'
], function (_, Collection) {
    'use strict';

    return Collection.extend({
        defaults: {
            visible: true,
            label: '',
            showLabel: true,
            required: false,
            template: 'ui/group/group',//Modify this for fieldset
            fieldTemplate: 'Vendor_Module/form/field',//Modify this for field
            breakLine: true,
            validateWholeGroup: false,
            additionalClasses: {}
        },

        /**
         * Extends this with defaults and config.
         * Then calls initObservable, iniListenes and extractData methods.
         */
        initialize: function () {
            this._super()
                ._setClasses();

            return this;
        },

        /**
         * Calls initObservable of parent class.
         * Defines observable properties of instance.
         *
         * @return {Object} - reference to instance
         */
        initObservable: function () {
            this._super()
                .observe('visible')
                .observe({
                    required: !!+this.required
                });

            return this;
        },

        /**
         * Extends 'additionalClasses' object.
         *
         * @returns {Group} Chainable.
         */
        _setClasses: function () {
            var additional = this.additionalClasses,
                classes;

            if (_.isString(additional)) {
                additional = this.additionalClasses.split(' ');
                classes = this.additionalClasses = {};

                additional.forEach(function (name) {
                    classes[name] = true;
                }, this);
            }

            _.extend(this.additionalClasses, {
                'admin__control-grouped': !this.breakLine,
                'admin__control-fields': this.breakLine,
                required:   this.required,
                _error:     this.error,
                _disabled:  this.disabled
            });

            return this;
        },

        /**
         * Defines if group has only one element.
         * @return {Boolean}
         */
        isSingle: function () {
            return this.elems.getLength() === 1;
        },

        /**
         * Defines if group has multiple elements.
         * @return {Boolean}
         */
        isMultiple: function () {
            return this.elems.getLength() > 1;
        },

        /**
         * Returns an array of child components previews.
         *
         * @returns {Array}
         */
        getPreview: function () {
            return this.elems.map('getPreview');
        }
    });
});
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/web/template/form/field.html

You can add your html here

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<div class="admin__field"
     visible="visible"
     css="$data.additionalClasses"
     attr="'data-index': index">
    <div class="admin__field-label" visible="$data.labelVisible">
        <label if="$data.label"  attr="for: uid">
            <span translate="label" attr="'data-config-scope': $data.scopeLabel" />
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="admin__field-control"
         css="'_with-tooltip': $data.tooltip, '_with-reset': $data.showFallbackReset && $data.isDifferedFromDefault">
        <render args="elementTmpl" ifnot="hasAddons()"/>

        <div class="admin__control-addon" if="hasAddons()">
            <render args="elementTmpl"/>

            <label class="admin__addon-prefix" if="$data.addbefore" attr="for: uid">
                <span text="addbefore"/>
            </label>
            <label class="admin__addon-suffix" if="$data.addafter" attr="for: uid">
                <span text="addafter"/>
            </label>
        </div>

        <render args="tooltipTpl" if="$data.tooltip"/>

        <render args="fallbackResetTpl" if="$data.showFallbackReset && $data.isDifferedFromDefault"/>

        <label class="admin__field-error" if="error" attr="for: uid" text="error"/>

        <div class="admin__field-note" if="$data.notice" attr="id: noticeId">
            <span translate="notice"/>
        </div>

        <div class="admin__additional-info" if="$data.additionalInfo" html="$data.additionalInfo"></div>

        <render args="$data.service.template" if="$data.hasService()"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to edit that in such a complicated way? I am not sure what you want to accomplish but anyway, here are some tips.

- make sure you are in the correct Store View
- edit your url rewrites in: Admin -> MARKETING -> SEO & Search -> URL Rewrites. Edit the URL you want to change.[elaborate explanation here](https://meetanshi.com/blog/magento-2-url-rewrite/)
- have a look here: https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/marketing/url-rewrite.html
- this is a fairly cheap extension that helps rewriting your urls from the command line: [URL Rewrite Regeneration](https://marketplace.magento.com/thlassche-regeneraterewrites.html)

Please let me know if any of this helped you out.

Comment: You did not understand the problem. The accepted answer solves it

Comment: You are welcome.